# How to parallel the Complete corelation of the one columns with others column

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have data frame which have 200k columns, I need one specific column's correlation with other columns but this code too slow.

```
Data <- data.frame    
# i for constant column is for others
'''
    while (i < 200000) {
      cor(
data[x , ], data[i,] 
) 
      i <- i + 1
    }

'''
```

Comment: What's your code doing?

Comment: Your code seems to be calculating correlation with the constant i, which is probably not what you want ...

Comment: Yes in one constant column corelation with others.

Answer (score 0):

```
cor(df[x],df[7:ncol(df)],use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

You can change the index 7:ncol(df) as you wish.